# What OS services does Windows UWP Apps for PC uses?

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, scanner

I am doing research on Windows WIA Architecture, and learning how Windows Scan Apps work with different service calls for working with WIA Scanner Services running as Part of STI COM in Svchost.dll.

Any Wia app loads Sti.dll COM stub to communicate with Wia service.

These makes all sense, unless I bring into picture UWP apps, which is not loading any STI.dll but instead loads something called Windows.Devices.Scanners.dll. Now as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.scanners) Windows.Devices.Scanners.dll uses Wia architecture internally to accomplish scan.

My question is if UWP is using WIA then why I'm not seeing the usual Wia stack and COM components in UWP.

Is UWP apps working with some kind of OS specific services which delegates all Wia native calls on behalf of UWP apps?

Comment: UWP uses a different framework because UWP apps are not windows-10 exclusive, but can also run on ARM devices. The whole idea behind UWP is that they are cross platform and can also run on Windows Mobile and can be installed and managed through the windows store. Also, UWP apps do not run on Windows 7 or earlier for the very same reason.

Comment: @LPChip Got it. In order to achieve cross platform, they have to call some services running natively? What are those is my question?

Comment: I don't know what they are, I just know how UWP works. I'm not a developer. My comment is just to explain why it is different. Because of the cross platform, UWP must have everything it supports natively in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So the answer is **RuntimeBroker.exe**, are the Microsoft process which delegates all the OS specific calls to PC.

For more information read [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/268240/what-is-runtime-broker-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/)